# Regex for getting the data from array

Tags: php, regex

I have the following data in my table column information

```
array( 'Email: Customer One <customer1@yahoo.com>. By employee: james@company.com.',
    'By employee: james@company.com. Department Head: Nickolas Jim.',
    'Email: Customer One <customer2@yahoo.com>. Status: currently employees.',
    'Email: Customer One <customer3@yahoo.com>. By employee: Mirza@company.com.'
)
```

Etc, etc

I have a need to get the 'By employee' from the array. In other words I am in a need of regex solution

ED. I just need the By employee if present..nothing else
So in above example I will have

```
By employee: james@company.com
By employee: james@company.com
By employee: Mirza@company.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested following sample code in php 5.4.5:

```
    <?php
$foo = array( 'Email: Customer One <customer1@yahoo.com>. By employee: james@company.com.',
              'By employee: james@company.com. Department Head: Nickolas Jim.',
              'Email: Customer One <customer2@yahoo.com>. Status: currently employees.',
              'Email: Customer One <customer3@yahoo.com>. By employee: Mirza@company.com.'
            );

for($i = 0; $i < count($foo); ++$i){
    if(0 >= preg_match('/\bBy employee: ([-\w._]+@[-\w]+(?:\.[-\w]+)*\.\w{2,4})\b/', $foo[$i], $matches))
        continue;  

    echo $matches[0] . "\n";
    echo $matches[1] . "\n";
    echo "\n";  
}            

?>
```

output:

```
        By employee: james@company.com
james@company.com

By employee: james@company.com
james@company.com

By employee: Mirza@company.com
Mirza@company.com
```

Comment: your solution gives me lots of extra stuff

Comment: this seems it will work. Can you please expalin me this part /\bBy employee: ([-\w._]+@[-\w]+(?:\.[-\w]+)*\.\w{2,4})\b/ thanks!

Comment: \bBy employee: (email address regex pattern)\b, \b is word boundary meta character

Comment: [-\w._] match '-', alphabet, number, underscore and dot. Some regex engine \w match underscode, you can remove it from character set.